# Dynamic 2D Array with realloc gives segmentation fault, but works with malloc

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, malloc, realloc

I have a problem with my dynamic 2d array. 
With `malloc` it worked. With `realloc`, it failed.

This dosen't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *const *argv) {

    unsigned ** gmatrix = NULL;
    int cap = 4;

    /*
    ...
    */

    gmatrix = realloc(gmatrix, 4 * sizeof(unsigned*));
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
        gmatrix[i] = realloc(gmatrix, cap* sizeof(unsigned));
    }
    // initialize:
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
        for(unsigned j =  0; j < cap; j++) {
            gmatrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

But this does:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *const *argv) {

    unsigned ** gmatrix = NULL;
    int cap = 4;

    /*
    ...
    */
    gmatrix = malloc(cap * sizeof(unsigned*));
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
        gmatrix[i] = malloc(cap* sizeof(unsigned));
    }
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
        for(unsigned j =  0; j < cap; j++) {
            gmatrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

In the first code part I get a segmentation fault error. Why?

Comment: Works fine for me! Are you sure this is the code generating the segfault? BTW, you forgot to free the allocated memory in both the programs.

Comment: oh there is an error in line: gmatrix[i] = malloc(cap* sizeof(unsigned)); it should be gmatrix[i] = realloc(gmatrix, cap* sizeof(unsigned));

Comment: Now it is corrected.

Comment: `calloc` would be better for the `gmatrix[i]` to avoid the need to zero the entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gmatrix[i] = realloc(gmatrix, cap* sizeof(unsigned));
```

should be

```
gmatrix[i] = realloc(gmatrix[i], cap* sizeof(unsigned));
```

Using `gmatrix` instead of `gmatrix[i]` will lead to [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and the segmentation fault which you experience is one of the side-effects of [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

**Edit**:

You should initialize `gmatrix[i]` to `NULL` after the first `malloc` as [@MattMcNabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555169/dynamic-2d-array-with-realloc-gives-segmentation-fault-but-works-with-malloc/30555290?noredirect=1#comment49182713_30555290). So use the following after the first call to `realloc`:

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
    gmatrix[i] = NULL;
    gmatrix[i] = realloc(gmatrix[i], cap* sizeof(unsigned));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It took my 2 hours yesterday.

Comment: This is also an error as `gmatrix[i]` is uninitialized before the call to realloc (unless OP intends that the "..." includes initialization of it)

Comment: @MattMcNabb , I had also thought about it. I thought that the first `realloc` initializes every row to `NULL`. It doesn't, right?

Comment: should I do a loop to initialize all `gmatrix[i]` with `NULL`?

Comment: @k2jj2k , Yes, but it is better to do it in the same loop as shown in the code in the "edit" section.

Comment: @CoolGuy but if I do it several times to REallocate (resize the array) it doesnt work, or? Because it overwrite my old one.

Comment: @k2jj2k , Are you telling that you may realloc more memory later? If so, you don't need `gmatrix[i] = NULL;`.

Comment: Ok. I think I got it. Thanks again!

Comment: @CoolGuy `realloc` doesn't do any initialization